# ScheduledJob of kubernetes never gets called

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I setup local environment with Vagrant by following [this](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes) CoreOS's way and currently a version of k8s is 1.4.0.

Now I want to try ScheduledJob which is introduced from 1.4.0 as an alpha resource. I first added a flag `- --runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true` in a `kube-apiserver.yaml`, then api-server is restarted.

Then I called `kubectl run hello --schedule="0/1 * * * ?" --restart=OnFailure --image=busybox -- /bin/sh -c "date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster"` by following the example [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/scheduled-jobs/).

The scheduled job was successfully created.

```
kubectl get scheduledjob
NAME           SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE    LAST-SCHEDULE
hello          0/1 * * * ?   False     0         <none>
```

But after that, no jobs are created no matter how long I'd waited.

```
kubectl get jobs --watch
NAME      DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
```

Is there something I have to add in my configuration?

`kubectl describe scheduledjobs` returns a following info:

```
Name:               hello
Namespace:          default
Schedule:           0/1 * * * ?
Concurrency Policy:     Allow
Suspend:            False
Starting Deadline Seconds:  <unset>
Image(s):           busybox
Selector:           <unset>
Parallelism:            <unset>
Completions:            <unset>
No volumes.
Labels:         run=hello
Last Schedule Time: <unset>
Active Jobs:        <none>
No events.%
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem with Kubernetes version: 1.4.3
FYI: I have raised on their github issues:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35508

However scheduledjob working fine for me with kubernetes version: 1.4.4

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I'm using CoreOS version's hypercube, so will try after they provide 1.4.4 image.